# pgfplot: Pin drawn on top of ybar stacked plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I need to label some components of a stacked bar plot in pgfplot, and I would like the pin to be visible to the center (rather than the edge).  I believe it is currently being drawn to the center of the bar (I can see it with no fill) but that it is being drawn under/before the bar.

I haven't found a reasonable way to do this, and it feels like there should be one.  My actual plot is more complicated than this, so I would rather not draw the entire thing in tikz.

Here is the code and image showing the pin-to-center showing with no fill:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ybar stacked,
          enlarge x limits=0.3,
            ymin=0]

          \addplot coordinates {(1,1)};
          \addplot[] coordinates {(1,1)};

          \node[coordinate,pin=right :{A}] at (axis cs:1,0.5) {};
          \node[coordinate,pin=right :{B}] at (axis cs:1,1.5) {};
       \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Pinning label to bar plot]

Apologies if I have completely missed something obvious!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can draw the pins before the bar:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ybar stacked,
          enlarge x limits=0.3,
            ymin=0]

          \node[coordinate,pin=right :{A}] at (axis cs:1,0.5) {};
          \node[coordinate,pin=right :{B}] at (axis cs:1,1.5) {};
          \addplot coordinates {(1,1)};
          \addplot[] coordinates {(1,1)};

       \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, I really did miss the obvious thing!  I assumed the drawing order was like in tikz with the later drawn things on top.