# ybar stacked: Position of labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to display some results of a performance test in a diagram as ybar stacked, but as you can see, some labels are printed over others and are hard to read (because of colors). Now I want labels on right side of bars, like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27715/pgfplot-pin-drawn-on-top-of-ybar-stacked-plot), but is there an automatic way to do this or I have to create all labels on my own? And can I make it so that lines are not going horizontal, and targeting the center of the stack element?

Current:

[image: Current]

Wished:

[image: Wished]

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.statistics}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    ybar stacked,
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 570,
    xtick=data,
    symbolic x coords={a, b},
    nodes near coords]
    \addplot coordinates{ (a, 2.9) (b, 2.9)};
    \addplot coordinates{ (a, 80) (b, 200)};
    \addplot coordinates{ (a, 400) (b, 100)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please show the code you have so far in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that we can start working with.

Comment: Sorry, had forgot to add it :/

Comment: Please read the link I posted in my earlier comment to understand what should (and what should not) be in an MWE.

Comment: New try. Hopefully it is enough now

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232049/ybar-stacked-position-of-labels

Answer (score 7):

This is a relatively short way to do so. Here is how it works:

The `name=X` gives the label a (temporary) name, `(X)`. And then I shift it so it is no longer overlapping bars.

On the other hand I need a reference to the original position. So I `.append code` with a node. You can search `node near coord` in `pgfplots.code.tex` to see where the former is appended. The trick is that the declaration of `(Y)` is following `(X)` so `(Y)` would be at the original position that the label should be.

Finally draw the line. Now you can modify the style yourself using `bend left` or something like `\draw[fill=none](Y.center)--+(10pt,0pt)--+(15pt,20pt)--(X);`. Notice that `.center` is necessary.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.statistics}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar stacked,
        /pgfplots/nodes near coords*/.append style={
            every node near coord/.style={
                name=X,
                shift={(30pt,20pt)}
            },
            scatter/@post marker code/.append code={
                \node(Y){};
                \draw(X)--(Y.center);
            }
        },
        nodes near coords,
        ymin=0,ymax=570,xtick=data,symbolic x coords={a,b},
    ]
    \addplot coordinates{(a,   2.9)(b,   2.9)};
    \addplot coordinates{(a,  80  )(b, 200  )};
    \addplot coordinates{(a, 400  )(b, 100  )};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice solution :). Is there a way to prevent automatically overlapping? E.g. if you have
    \addplot coordinates{(a,   2.9)(b,   2.9)};
    \addplot coordinates{(a,   2.9)(b,   2.9)};
    \addplot coordinates{(a,  80  )(b, 200  )};
    \addplot coordinates{(a, 400  )(b, 100  )};

Comment: I guess you mean the following: (1) If the current subbar is high enough, put the label **inside** (2) otherwise use a **call out** node. For the former it is easy to do such checking. For the latter it would be enough to have `shift={(20pt,2*\coordinates@count*\text@size)}`. But I doubt whether such counter exists.

Comment: Oh, by the way, you should edit your question so people will easily understand what is going on.