# Stacked bar chart overlapping values

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

How can I overcome the issue I'm having with the chart below:

[image: Stacked Bar Chart]

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\caption{\label{tab:kdd99chartProt}Attack representation per protocol within     KDD99 10\% dataset} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar stacked, ymin=0,  
bar shift=0pt,
ymajorgrids,
bar width=30pt,
ylabel=Representation in \%,
width=250pt,
symbolic x coords={TCP,UDP,ICMP},
legend pos=outer north east,
xtick=data,
ymax=85,
nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta \%}
]

\addplot [black,fill=bblue,mark=none] coordinates {
({TCP},23)
({UDP},0.2)
({ICMP},57)};

\addplot [black,fill=rred,mark=none] coordinates {
({TCP},16)
({UDP},4)
({ICMP},0.2)};
\legend{Attack,Normal}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome! How did you produce that chart? We can't possibly help you fix your code if we don't know what you did.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I've added the code. Thank you!

Comment: @user2459813 Well, that's going to be a tough one. You are comparing 0.2% with 57%, and also 4% with 0.2% in a 0-80% scale. No wonder the numbers will overlap. As far as I can see you either tweak with `nodes near coords style` and make the font smaller, put the nodes to the left and give them some shifting ***or*** place the nodes manually. I think the second option is the best one (you don't have many data points).

Comment: Could you perhaps guide me on how to place the nodes manually?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/232551/51022

Comment: @user2459813, did the link provided by Symbol 1 help you to solve your problem or do you need further assistance?

Comment: Hi yes the link did assist me!